# In windows, what do I type in powershell to connect my dApp to a liteserver?

Tags: dapps, windows, frontend

> In windows powershell, what do I type to connect metamask to a liteserver?  >

Comment: MetaMask is a plugin in your browser. To connect to it you deploy javascript in the front end code that is loaded in the browser, your backend cannot access to the MetaMask plugin directly.